# Run a script when Steam Streaming starts

Tags: windows-7, powershell, shell-script, streaming, steam

I'm using Steam in-home streaming from my desktop PC to my living room.  The only problem is, my monitor and my living room screen have different resolutions, so every time I switch I need to change the output resolution, and I'd like to stop doing it manually.

I've [found some options for changing screen resolution with a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581182/batch-file-to-change-screen-resolution-in-windows-7), now I just need a way to run a script when Steam Streaming starts.  Streaming is initiated from the remote device, so I need to be able to detect when streaming starts, then run the script.